# Upper limit of energy carried by one photon

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, frequency, wavelength

energy carried by one photon, $E = hυ$ where $υ$ is frequency and $h =$ planck constant. Is there any upper limit to how much energy one photon can carry? or any upper limit of frequency?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159922/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43063/2451